# yasnippets not work: yas--table-get-create: Symbol’s function definition is void: record

Tags: emacs

I install yasnippet and yasnippet-snippets packages but when I editing in c-mode tye yasnippet Menu did show up but there is no snippets automatically loaded. I need to manually specify the code every time. I think it should be a configuration problem, but when I try to use "load everything" in the menu an error showed up:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function record)
  record(yas--table "antlr-mode" #s(hash-table size 65 test equal rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...)) #s(hash-table size 65 test equal rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...)) nil (keymap))
  yas--table-get-create(antlr-mode)
  yas-define-snippets(antlr-mode (("target" "<target name=\"${1:compile}\" ${2:other}>\n        $0\n</target>" "target" nil nil nil "e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-snippets-20190422.1416/snippets/antlr-mode/target" nil nil) ("prop" "<property name=\"${1:name}\" value=\"${2:value}\" />\n$0" "property" nil nil nil "e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-snippets-20190422.1416/snippets/antlr-mode/property" nil nil) ("proj" "<project name=\"${1:test}\" default=\"${2:compile}\" basedir=\"${3:.}\">\n\n$0\n</project>" "project" nil nil nil "e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-snippets-20190422.1416/snippets/antlr-mode/project" nil nil)))
  yas--load-directory-2("e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-snippets-20190422.1416/snippets/antlr-mode" antlr-mode)
  yas--load-directory-1("e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-snippets-20190422.1416/snippets/antlr-mode" antlr-mode)
  apply(yas--load-directory-1 ("e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-snippets-20190422.1416/snippets/antlr-mode" antlr-mode))
  #[128 "\302\300\303\301\"\"\207" [yas--load-directory-1 ("e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-snippets-20190422.1416/snippets/antlr-mode" antlr-mode) apply append] 6 "\n\n(fn &rest ARGS2)"]()
  yas/load-directory("~/.emacs.d/elpa/yasnippet-snippets-20190422.1416/snippets/")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-583469> nil "e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/emacs/myautocomplete.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3100
  load-with-code-conversion("e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/emacs/myautocomplete.el" "e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/emacs/myautocomplete.el" nil t)
  load("myautocomplete.el" nil t t)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1429
  load-with-code-conversion("e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.emacs" "e:/baidu_cloud/new_home/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "\205\266
```

Answer (score 1):

`record` is a built in function (defined in C) in Emacs 26, and according to NEWS it was added in 26.1.  You probably need to update Emacs.